# How to align the pricing tables?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

first of all, I would like to apologize if my question is not clear.
As you can see from the pictures I am trying to create a pricing table to include on my girlfriend's website which is built on the Wix platform. I've got the code from W3 schools for creating pricing table, but I need more than 3 columns. That's why I have copied the code (the divs) which create the columns, but as you can see they are not in line with the others.

Another thing is the button, when I am scaling down the webpage opened with Live server on Google chrome you can see how the button looks like.

So my questions are, how I can make 2 more pricing tables to look good and also how I can make the so when opened on different screen sizes to be responsive.

Regards

[Here's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yrlb.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .columns {
        float: left;
        width: 33.3%;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      .price {
        list-style-type: none;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      .price:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      }

      .price .header {
        background-color: #6f8bab20;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-size: 25px;
      }

      .price li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .price .grey {
        background-color: #eee;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .button {
        background-color: #253c57;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      #price {
        font-size: 50px;
      }

      .grey-vip {
        height: 172px;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .columns {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 style="text-align: center">Responsive Pricing Tables</h2>
    <p style="text-align: center">
    </p>

    <div class="columns">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
        <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
        <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
        <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
        <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
        <li>Home/gym based</li>
        <li>Video Demonstration</li>
        <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
        <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
        <li class="grey">
          <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="columns">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header" style="background-color: #65e6f7">
          Vip Online Coaching
        </li>
        <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 120 / month</li>
        <li>Fully tailored macronutrient/nutritional guide</li>
        <li>Fully tailored training programme</li>
        <li>Exercise technique analysis</li>
        <li>Supplement guidance</li>
        <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
        <li>Weekly check-ins</li>

        <li class="grey">
          <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header">Nutrition Coaching</li>
        <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
        <li>Adapted to your goals, personal preferences and allergies</li>
        <li>Fully tailored nutritional plan</li>
        <li>Shopping guidance</li>
        <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
        <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
        <li class="grey">
          <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header">3 Months Online Coaching</li>
        <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 300 / month</li>
        <li>Fully tailored macronutrient/nutritional guidance</li>
        <li>Fully tailored training programme</li>
        <li>Supplement guidance</li>
        <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
        <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
        <li class="grey">
          <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header">Video Consultation</li>
        <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 40 / month</li>
        <li>Overcoming healthy lifestyle barriers</li>
        <li>Psychonutritional barriers</li>
        <li>Training questions</li>
        <li class="grey">
          <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A CONSULTATION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For your columns, try to change `.columns` css class `width` with 25% (4 columns) or 20% (5 columns). Now you have 33% (3 columns)

Comment: To have them align with each other, you have to set `height` Of your css class `.columns` by instance 200px

Comment: Thanks, @Camille, really appreciate it. Do you know how to make them all the same size in height and width even if the content (the text) in some of them is more? 

See photos attached: 
https://ibb.co/MPBK16M
https://ibb.co/P9YMtJh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an `div` and place the columns inside that div and added font-size for button so the button won't collapse in the smaller device. Please check the below code and copy paste and run. If you find this, useful please vote the answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .containers{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .container{
        padding: 10px;
      }
    
      .price {
        list-style-type: none;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      .price:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      }

      .price .header {
        background-color: #6f8bab20;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-size: 25px;
      }

      .price li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .price .grey {
        background-color: #eee;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .button {
        background-color: #253c57;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      #price {
        font-size: 50px;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .columns {
          width: 100%;
        }
        .button{
            font-size: 12px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 style="text-align: center">Responsive Pricing Tables</h2>
    <p style="text-align: center">
    </p>
    <div class="containers">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="price">
                <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
                <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
                <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
                <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
                <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
                <li>Home/gym based</li>
                <li>Video Demonstration</li>
                <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
                <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
                <li class="grey">
                  <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="price">
                <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
                <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
                <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
                <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
                <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
                <li>Home/gym based</li>
                <li>Video Demonstration</li>
                <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
                <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
                <li class="grey">
                  <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="price">
                <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
                <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
                <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
                <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
                <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
                <li>Home/gym based</li>
                <li>Video Demonstration</li>
                <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
                <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
                <li class="grey">
                  <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="price">
                <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
                <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
                <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
                <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
                <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
                <li>Home/gym based</li>
                <li>Video Demonstration</li>
                <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
                <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
                <li class="grey">
                  <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="price">
                <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
                <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
                <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
                <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
                <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
                <li>Home/gym based</li>
                <li>Video Demonstration</li>
                <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
                <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
                <li class="grey">
                  <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output screen:
[image]

Responsive as well:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Prabaharan, really appreciate it. Do you know how to make them all the same size in height and width even if the content (the text) in some of them is more. 

See photos attached: 
https://ibb.co/MPBK16M
https://ibb.co/P9YMtJh

Comment: @Anatoliy Draganov - If this answer solves your issue, you should accept it (click the green tick).